# Linux - scan for mac address and host name

Tags: linux, mac, hostname

I have a list of MAC addresses that I would like to get the host names for.  I've tried a number of different ways but haven't come up with an answer.  Looking for command line tool.

Comment: "_Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question._"

Comment: What kind of hostname? DNS, Samba, etc? nmap will do DNS names for most scan types: https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html

Comment: No DNS available on my lan. I need device names like roku or iphone etc

Comment: try installing nmap and running (as root): `nmap -sP 192.168.1.*` where `192.168.1.` is the Network ID for your LAN. It may not be able to get all the hostnames though, as not all devices provide it via the same protocols.